# SQLite insert if not exist else increase integer value

Tags: python, sqlite, exists, not-exists

I need a way to insert a value if the value doesn't exist and if it does it should increase that value by another variable.

This is what my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(
      Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      Date TEXT,
      Quantity INTEGER
```

Whenever i add a date to the database, with a quantity i want it to, add the quantity to the "quantity" in table. So every "Date" would only have 1 "Quantity" assigned.

Just a small example:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Date, Quantity) VALUES('%s', Quantity+%s)) % ('12/5/2013', 20);
```

If there already is a record that looks like ('12/5/2013', 5)
it would be ('12/5/2013', 25) instead.

I found 1 very similar question, but i don't understand, how i also make the integer increase..
[Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823170/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-or-increase-if-exists-in-sqlite)

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you don't understand in the answer you linked to? The `replace or insert` sounds pretty self-explenary. The  `coalesce` is new to me but according to the docs it returns the first non-null argument passed into, So if the select returns null (as there is no record for given date yet) the second paramter is used as a fallback. In your case you just don't want `coalesce(SELECT val+1 …, 1)` but something like  `coalesce(SELECT quantity+quantity …, quantitty)` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have only one column for each date, then you should declare it as UNIQUE, or even as the PRIMARY KEY for the table.

If you do that, then you can declare the Quantity column as INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0. Your table would then be defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
    Date TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Then when you want to add to a specific date, you run:

```
# assuming 'db' is your sqlite3 database
date_to_insert = '12/5/2013'
amount_to_add = 20
db.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table(Date) VALUES(?)', (date_to_insert,))
db.execute('UPDATE table SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE Date = ?', (amount_to_add, date_to_insert))
```

Comment: Awesome that works, i declared Date as UNIQUE and Id as PRIMARY. Works like a charm.