# Insert or replace not replacing in some cases with python sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am writing script that scans through a bunch of news articles and stores in an SQLite database all of the individual words and how many times each word appears. In order to do this I am using `INSERT OR REPLACE` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823170/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-or-increase-if-exists-in-sqlite) SO question. The problem I'm having is that sometimes it doesn't replace when it should. What I think is causing this is that since sql queries happen in parallel, one word is being inserted into the database and by the time my script finds the next appearance of that same word, it hasn't finished inserting it into the database so it makes a new entry (i.e. inserts instead of replaces). Is this a valid concern? If so, how do I make my script wait until the previous sql query has finished before executing the next one?

Here is the code that is inserting/replacing:

```
def incremement_or_insert(subject, word):
    db = connect_to_db()
    c = db.cursor()
    query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO subject_words (subject, word, count) VALUES (?, ?, COALESCE((SELECT count + 1 FROM subject_words WHERE subject = ? AND word = ?), 1));"
    c.execute(query, (subject, word, subject, word))
    db.commit()
    db.close
```

Comment: I don't think sqlite has `ON DUPLICATE`, at least I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: There is nothing parallel in your code. In any case, SQLite has no write parallelism.